# Why my Ubuntu server is unable to connent to an address while Ubuntu on Windows could?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ftp, wget

I want to download [a file from The European Bioinformatics Institute](ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/run/ERR258/ERR2583795/IK002.bam). When I use wget or axel in my lab's Ubuntu server, it pauses forever. However, when I use Ubuntu installed on my Windows as linux subsystem for windows, it works well. Note, the server and my linux are using the same public IP, so they ought to be equally reachable to the ebi server. I have tried to ping ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk. Again, it works well on my PC while pauses forever on the server:

```
ping ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk
PING oy-ftp-sra.ebi.ac.uk (193.62.192.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

This problem has haunted myself and other lab members. Hope someone can help.

Thank you!

---

Wget logs for IK002.bam.bai:

My own machine:

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/run/ERR258/ERR2583795/IK002.bam.bai
Will not apply HSTS. The HSTS database must be a regular and
non-world-writable file. ERROR: could not open HSTS store at
'/home/john/.wget-hsts'. HSTS will be disabled.
--2019-09-02 16:20:54--  ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/run/ERR258/ERR2583795/IK002.bam.bai
           => ‘IK002.bam.bai’ Resolving ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk (ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk)... 193.62.192.7 Connecting to ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk
(ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk)|193.62.192.7|:21... connected. Logging in as
anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /vol1/run/ERR258/ERR2583795 ... done.
==> SIZE IK002.bam.bai ... 7987872
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR IK002.bam.bai ... done. Length: 7987872 (7.6M) (unauthoritative)

IK002.bam.bai      100%[===============>]   7.62M  60.3KB/s    in 2m
12s

2019-09-02 16:23:13 (59.1 KB/s) - ‘IK002.bam.bai’ saved [7987872]
```

Server:

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/run/ERR258/ERR2583795/IK002.bam.bai
--2019-09-02 16:22:46--  ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/run/ERR258/ERR2583795/IK002.bam.bai
           => ‘IK002.bam.bai’ Resolving ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk (ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk)... 193.62.192.7 Connecting to ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk
(ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk)|193.62.192.7|:21... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2019-09-02 16:24:58--  ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/run/ERR258/ERR2583795/IK002.bam.bai  
(try: 2) => ‘IK002.bam.bai’ Connecting to ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk
(ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk)|193.62.192.7|:21... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

---

```
$ sudo traceroute --icmp 193.62.192.7
traceroute to 193.62.192.7 (193.62.192.7), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *

$ ip -4 route get 193.62.192.7
193.62.192.7 via 10.10.0.254 dev eno1 src 10.10.0.195 uid 1000
    cache

$ ip -4 route show match 193.62.192.7
default via 10.10.0.254 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 10.10.0.195 metric 100
```

Comment: Can you show us wget log files for both machines?

Comment: From your server: Can you ping "ac.uk"? Can you ping any other domain, like "superuser.com"?

Comment: @Sevron Since ac.uk is a root domain like .edu, it can't be pinged. Pinging superuser.com works well. I have also tried to download using ip address. Still, it only works on my PC.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl OK.

Comment: Run `tcpdump -n -v -i eth0 "host 193.62.192.7"` on the problematic system – does this show any packets while wget is trying to connect? If it does, are they all outgoing packets or does it also show responses coming in?

Comment: @grawity No response. It shows hte following in loop:    10.10.0.195.35514 > 193.62.192.7.21: Flags [S], cksum 0x8c41 (incorrect -> 0xdb8a), seq 3313447536, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3184602561 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:43:04.411648 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12987, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)

Comment: Next questions: `sudo traceroute --icmp 193.62.192.7`, `ip -4 route get 193.62.192.7`, `ip -4 route show match 193.62.192.7`

Comment: @grawity sudo traceroute --icmp 193.62.192.7
traceroute to 193.62.192.7 (193.62.192.7), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *

Comment: @grawity ip -4 route get 193.62.192.7
193.62.192.7 via 10.10.0.254 dev eno1 src 10.10.0.195 uid 1000
    cache

Comment: @grawity ip -4 route show match 193.62.192.7
default via 10.10.0.254 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 10.10.0.195 metric 100

Comment: Why is all this in comments and not added to the post in readable format?

Comment: @harrymc Added to the question.

Comment: Questions: (1) Do you mean that the server and the Ubuntu machine are behind the same router? (2) Is the Windows machine in the same internal network? (3) If both are in the same network why use the Internet to communicate?

Comment: Is 10.10.0.254 your lab's actual gateway, and is it the same for both machines? If you run tcpdump with `-e` option added, does it show the correct MAC for the destination?

Comment: Hi, welcome on SuperUser. Check the versions of wget (`wget --version`) and eventually update the old one. Did you understand if you have the port 21 _open_ on the _server_? In some installation is closed for security reasons (usually ftp port 21 sftp port 22...). Please [edit] your post adding the information.

Comment: @harrymc (1) Yes. (2) Yes. (3) No. They use local network to communicate, but ebi downloads are only accessible by my PC.

Comment: @Hastur They are both 1.19.4. I don't know. But they can both download superuser.com.

Comment: @grawity In my local machine, $ip -4 route get 193.62.192.7 showsnone 193.62.192.7 via 192.168.163.1 dev wifi0 proto unspec src 192.168.163.142 . It seems it's different.

Comment: @john try to download with wget from another frp site...